# What are the options that I have to develop a new application for the web

Tags: html, delphi, intraweb, raudus

I am looking to create a new application for a school. That there is the financial and academical part. This school is already using tablets for students.

I consider interesting the new concept of interface of Metro UI, Like having dashboards of the data. I like some visual effects.

My background is Delphi (up to Xe2), SQL. I like the RAD approach of delphi. Recently I made an application using B4A that is a visual basic like compiler for android, and i was impressed on how fast I learned (never made anything on vb) and deployed a nice looking app.

There are a lot of new devices out there, specially tablets, and I foresee that I can use tablets in the place of Windows PCs and it will bring less costs and much easier to deal with.

However the server is a windows server box, I know not much of linux and dont see much value in get out of windows servers.

So, I was looking in a way of doing RAD developement, preferably with Delphi, but could be other language.

Delphi options are not clear to me: intraweb (even with the TMS components) seems to not be much used. I dont see sites with it, and seems it is not possible to have rich graphical options, for at least emulate windows metro style (with aproximate quality)

Raudus is still unclear, The option with Ext js was great but was dropped from the project.

What option that i have to create a RAD application that is multiplatform and web based? Ria could be getting out of map for the next years because HTML 5 is opening a new approach.

Comment: You have to split it into UI and logic part. Web development with any web framework (even now unknown to you) is easier than going the delphi way. Maybe CakePHP is the right one for the logical part, but there is a lot more. For the UI part you should have a look at jQuery

Comment: Far too vague to answer. And I see about 30 questions in there. But check out `HTML5Builder`. It's got a lot of Delphi in its DNA. It was once called Delphi4PHP then PHPBuilder, now it's HTML5Builder. It's got fabulous support for mobile and device web browser app development, plus regular desktop-browser web-app development, and can handle both the client side (HTML/CS/Javascript) and the server side (PHP) construction.